# what are the special cases of the covariance matrices () for EM algorithm for a Gaussian mixture

Tags: covariance, maximum-likelihood, gaussian

Consider 5 various forms of the covariance matrices  in a Gaussian mixture model. The original problem was: Derive the EM equations for maximizing the likelihood function under such a model.

$$
p(x|\mu, \Sigma)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^ \frac{d}{2}|\Sigma_k|^ \frac{1}{2} } 
                 exp[-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu_k)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_k)]
$$

I know that to derive the EM equations, one should first set the covariance with respect to its form (given in the following), then compute the `MLE`. i.e. `first` compute the log-likelihood, `second` derivate w.r.t $\mu$ or $\Sigma$ or, $\alpha$. `third` set the derivative to zero and extract the desired variable.

$$
L(\theta)= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^k  \gamma(z_{ik}) [ 
 \alpha_{k}+\frac{1}{(2\pi)^ \frac{d}{2}|\Sigma_k|^ \frac{1}{2} } 
                 exp[-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu_k)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_k)] ]
$$

##### 5 different types of covariance matrix

1. Σ<sub>k</sub>=Σ.
   this means that all of the elements in the matrix are equal.
   we should substitute the Σ with Σ to solve this case.
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a & a & a \\
   a & a & a \\
   a & a & a
   \end{bmatrix} \qquad
   \end{equation*}
2. Σ<sub>k</sub>=arbitrary.
   this means that the elements in the matrix have different values.
   we should substitute the Σ with Σk to solve this case.
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a & b & c \\
   d & e & f \\
   g & h & i
   \end{bmatrix} \qquad
   \end{equation*}
3. Σ<sub>k</sub>=σ<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup>I. 
   this means that only diagonal elements are non-zero but they have different values.
   we should substitute the Σ with σ<sup>d</sup> to solve this case.

   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & b & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & c
   \end{bmatrix} \qquad
   \end{equation*}
4. Σ<sub>k</sub>=σ<sup>2</sup>I. 
   this means that only diagonal elements are non-zero and they are all equal.
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & a & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & a
   \end{bmatrix} \qquad
   \end{equation*}
5. Σ<sub>k</sub>=diag({σ<sup>2</sup><sub>jk</sub> }<sup>d</sup><sub>k=1</sub> )
   I don't understand what form does it has? if it is diagonal, its diagonal elements are either equal (form 4), or they are different (form 3).what should I put instead of Σ to solve this case?
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   ? & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & ? & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & ?
   \end{bmatrix} \qquad
   \end{equation*}

I understand cases 1 to 4. But, I have a hard time understanding case 5. any ideas? please draw a matrix and show the difference between the elements in case 5. and what I should put instead of Σ to solve this case?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You mean $\Sigma_k=\operatorname{diag}\left(\left\{\sigma^2_{jk}\right\}_{k=1}^d\right)=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma^2_{j1},\ldots,\sigma^2_{jd})$? What is the dimension of $\Sigma_k$?

Comment: @Community done. is it clear now?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'm not sure! but the notation suggests you are correct. and about dimension of sigma, it says k is from 1 to d.